# group vs. groupe

Tags: traduction, homonymes, différence

Quelle est la différence entre `un groupe` et `un group`?

En google translate et https://www.deepl.com/en/translator, les deux se traduisent apparemment en `a group` en anglais et un `een groep` en néerlandais.

Comment: Pour clarifier l'historique la question: Je suis néerlandophone mais professionnellement, j’écris beaucoup en anglais et parfois en français. Je doutait si je devait traduire `groep` comme `group` ou `groupe` en français et le correcteur orthographique de Microsoft laissait passer les deux, alors.

Comment: On the closing of this question: Please read the clarification in the comment before you judge

Comment: Reformulate your question including your comment in the question and ask for a re-opening. The question is not about "group" vs. "groupe" but why both words "group" & "groupe" are translated by the same English word. It might be rejected again as not fit for this site, but I personally know no other site on SE where you could ask the question since there is no translation site on the SE network and it would not fit ELU since answering the question needs a good knowledge of French to be able to use a good monolingual dictionary in French.

Comment: This is really a question about automatic translators and not about language. Automatic translation services such as Google translate and DeepL try hard to produce _some_ output, whether the output is sensible or not. **They try to correct for typos!** (Try it with other typos for *groupe* or any other word. Notice also that it's context-sensitve, e.g. DeepL fr→en translates “un grope” as “a grope” (it didn't figure *grope* out so it left it unchanged) but “un grope de personnes” as “a group of people”.) Just because the translator did something doesn't tell you the input is makes sense.

Comment: Nope! I mentioned automatic translators as a funny detail. I mentioned correctors because they pointed out both words exist. The only thing I was really interested in is why both words exist. Now, actually I don't care you closed the question. I now have the answer, including the common origin of both words.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' I beg to differ, it is **also** a question about French vocabulary, it's just not properly formulated by someone whose mother tongue isn't French and new to the site. And the close reason is not good enough because the word is very difficult to find in a bilingual dictionary. Impossible online and only found in a 50 year old French English Harrap's standard. And I doubt all the people who asked for the question to be closed  knew there was such a word as *group* in French.

Comment: @DirkHorsten Frankly, to ask about a word where one form of it is so archaic as to be quasi-meaningless without context is not fair play. In general, what Gilles says is correct, of course.

Comment: The fact that apart from me four people upvoted the answer proofs it is a question worth asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Effectivement il existe bien en français deux mots différents : « group » et « groupe ».  Nous nous trouvons devant un cas qui montre la limite des traducteurs en ligne, aussi bons soient-ils comme DeepL, car ils ne sont basés que sur des corpus électroniques relativement récents.  Ici le robot ne reconnait pas le mot « group » non contenu dans le corpus mais l'assimile à son homonyme « groupe » comme le montre [cet essai](https://www.deepl.com/translator#fr/en/Le%20marchand%20de%20bois%20devait%20envoyer%20%C3%A0%20son%20confr%C3%A8re%20un%20group%20de%20quinze%20mille%20francs.) fait avec un extrait de [Ponson du Terrail](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Alexis_de_Ponson_du_Terrail) (19<sup>e</sup> siècle<sup>1</sup>).

Un « **group** » est un sac contenant des valeurs ou de l'argent et qui circule cacheté. Ce terme est très vieilli et n'est plus utilisé et je soupçonne que la majorité des Français ne le connaissent pas<sup>2</sup>.

Or les deux mots qui sont homonymes en français ne se traduisent pas de la même façon en anglais. La seule traduction que je trouve pour le mot français « group » (*Harrap's French-English dictionary*, 1970) est :

> *Bank:Comm: sealed bag of cash of specie (for transmission to or from branch office)*.

Aucun dictionnaire bilingue en ligne ne donne de traduction de « group ».

Contre vérification dans l'OED : le mot *group* avec ce sens de *sealed bag of cash* n'y figure pas. On peut dire qu'en anglais il n'y a pas de mot spécifique pour traduire le français « group ».

Pour ce qui est de la correspondance avec le néerlandais je ne peux rien dire.

Il faut noter que les deux mots « group » et « groupe » sont issus du même mot italien *gruppo*, le sens de « sac » en italien étant semble-t-il antérieur à celui de « rassemblement de choses ou de personnes ».

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> [Page d'où est tirée la phrase](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/M%C3%A9moire_d_un_gendarme/oPG8DQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22un%20group%22&pg=PT136&printsec=frontcover).</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Le terme employé de nos jours est « sac de transport de fonds »</sup>

Comment: Merci. Les traductions venaient juste de l'internet. Ces robots ne traduisent pas ce qu'ils ne comprennent pas, hors `a group` en anglais. Mais comment alors comprendre ce `een groep` en nerlandais?

Comment: @DirkHorsten Peut-être par le même mécanisme si c'est une recherche sur internet ? Aucun des quelques dictionnaires bilingues français anglais en ligne (même sérieux) ainsi que les dictionnaires bilingues papier récents que j'ai consultés ne proposent d'entrée pour *group*, le mot est passé dans l'oubli. Peut-être consulter un dictionnaire bilingue papier français néerlandais assez ancien ?

Comment: On ne sait même pas ce que le posteur entend par group. Ce n'est pas un mot en français aujourd'hui.

Comment: @Lambie S'il avait su ce que c'était il n'aurait pas posé la question. Et pour moi la question est parfaitement claire. Au départ il est probablement tombé sur ce qui est une mauvaise reconnaissance automatique (voir son edit), et il se trouve quel le mot mal interprété par l'automate existe.

Comment: @Lambie Un mot reste un mot même s'il n'est plus guère employé et il existe même s'il n'est pas connu de beaucoup de gens. Il se trouve dans des dictionnaires français (DHLF, DCLF, wiktionnaire, TLFi, GDEL,Grand Larousse, Petit Robert et probablement d'autres) par contre c'est un fait  il est ignoré par les dictionnaires bilingues en ligne.

Comment: @Lambie Dans le cas présent le contexte ne changerait rien à la question. Il existe bien deux mots homonymes : groupe et group.

Comment: Comment sais-tu que le posteur savait qu'il y avait deux mots différents? Rien ne nous l'lndique, n'est-ce pas?